# Why is it called the fold?

Tags: terminology, scrolling, screen-resolution

Why is the place where the visible screen (on load) ends called the Fold?  I have a hard time even writing out the definition for it, but when someone says The Fold, I know exactly what they mean.

Why is it called *the fold*, or *above the fold*?

Is the term appropriate to use when working with non-developers?

Comment: With this question, I am an old man.

Comment: The fold isn't in the same place for every user though, it depends on the size of their window, right?

Comment: @Michael: Generally, a web site should be designed so that *most* users will be able to see enough without scrolling to know that the balance of the page is likely to be of interest, and so that uses who want to use common navigation links will not have to scroll to find them.  It doesn't matter if many users get to see a lot of information beyond the bare minimum; what's important is that even users with small-but-not-unusually-small screens don't have to scroll excessively.

Comment: It should also be noted that 'the fold'--as being an issue on the web--is a myth: http://boxesandarrows.com/blasting-the-myth-of-the-fold/ http://www.cxpartners.co.uk/cxblog/the_myth_of_the_page_fold_evidence_from_user_testing/ http://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll

Comment: So, in other words, it's not a relative term at all for UX on the web.

Comment: @DA01 I love that those three sites have essentially zero side content below the fold.

Comment: @harbichidian there is no fold. So, there may be no side content below the fold on *your* particular computer screen, but there's plenty on mine. That's one of the points they're trying to make.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's from print newspapers; back in the day when broadsheets were more common, they were usually presented folded in half vertically, so the most important part of the front page was the portion "above the fold", which is the first thing most people see when they see the newspaper. Analogously, this is the first part of the website you see when a page loads, before the user unfolds the newspaper or scrolls down.

With non-developers, it depends on their experience with jargon. Designers would generally understand what you mean, but the average layperson might not, since there's no clear foldable portion of a website or a screen.

Comment: Indeed, the average lay person might not already know this jargon, but it is an appropriate term to use with them. You simply need to explain it first. Fortunately, the metaphor is simple enough that most people will get it straight away.

Comment: Please site sources. [FineDictionary.com's Idioms for *Above*](http://www.finedictionary.com/above.html) corroborates this etymology: "Above the fold - If a news story is important, it will be above the fold- in the top half of the page of a newspaper."

Comment: @3nafish: Sorry, I'm not super familiar with the rules still... I answered out of my personal general knowledge, is it expected that I should normally back that up with external sources also?

Comment: @rachteo, yes whenever possible.  Otherwise, it reads as opinion.  For things that truly are general knowledge, it's easy to find a supporting source to demonstrate that they're more than just wild guesses.  Without emphasizing citation of sources in answers, we end up with questions like [the one about washing machine windows](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50259/why-do-washing-machines-have-windows) where most of the answers are random speculation, bringing down the quality of the site.

Comment: It has nothing to do with delivery.   When delivered, newspapers were/are usually rolled up.  Newspaper vending machines (news racks) displayed folded newspapers.  The portion above the fold was very important to get people interested in buying the paper from the vending machine. Photo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspaper_vending_machine#mediaviewer/File:WZ_Zeitungsautomat.jpg

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Sorry, you're absolutely right. I should have said "presented". I'll edit my answer to reflect that. Newspapers in my neighbourhood are usually delivered folded but I shouldn't have assumed that's standard across areas.

Comment: This term is partially deprecated now due to the large differing number of screen & window sizes, and subsequent differences in the position of the fold. Also note - showing partial content 'above' the fold can encourage users to scroll further. Recommend book 'Don't make me think' for further reading.

Answer (score 55):

It comes from newspapers which are folded in half. Above the fold refers to content that is visible without unfolding or turning the newspaper over to see the 2nd half. This term was adapted to websites and their content that is visible without scrolling.

Here is a picture of a newspaper. 
[image]
Everything you can see is above the fold.

Answer (score 14):

The history of the term "Above the fold" comes from newspapers where the articles at the top were most visible when the newspaper was folded. To quote [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Above_the_fold)

> Above the fold is the upper half of the front page of a newspaper
>   where an important news story or photograph is often located. Papers
>   are often displayed to customers folded so that only the top half of
>   the front page is visible. Thus, an item that is "above the fold" may
>   be one that the editors feel will entice people to buy the paper.
>   Alternatively, it reflects a decision, on the part of the editors,
>   that the article is one of the day's most important. By extension, the
>   space above the fold is also preferred by advertisers, since it is the
>   most prominent and visible even when the newspaper is on stands.

With regards to developers, while most developers I work with understand the above the fold term, if users or stakeholders dont understand, I explain it **as the content that is visible when you first load a page and what you can see without scrolling.**

[image]

However do note, above the fold is a relative term as it depends upon the resolution and the form factor of the device used to view the content.

I also recommend reading this [witty article about the fold](http://www.iampaddy.com/lifebelow600/)

Comment: A site should use what's above the fold to convince a reader that there's something good below the fold.  To use the newspaper analogy, if nothing above the fold was of interest, nobody would read the paper; if everything of interest was above the fold, many people would read the paper, but nobody would buy it.  Once people are drawn to a page, they'll proceed further, but if the page doesn't draw their attention quickly they're likely to leave and never return unless they've been told elsewhere what to expect.